# My / her - word choice

Tags: possessives, possessive-adjectives

Which of the two options is more appropriate for this sentence? Why?

I am a 25-year-old girl who likes interacting with people and practising **my / her**  English.

Comment: At 25 you may be a bit old to be a "girl",  but you are only as young as you feel...

Comment: I guess "her" is strictly grammatically correct, but "my" doesn't sound bad to me either.

Comment: You don't need her or my.

Comment: You can also use "likes to interact" and "to practice English".

Answer (score 0):

No determiner is needed here, so you avoid the issue by just saying "practising English".

If a possessive is needed you can often rephrase:

> I'm a 25-year-old girl who likes playing with (my/her) dogs.

> I'm a 25-year-old girl, and I like to play with my dogs.

There is no doubt that the second example has "my".

If you do need a possessive, and rephrasing isn't possible you should probably use "her", however it is not optimal.

Comment: This answer assumes that rephrasing is necessary, but I don't see anything wrong with the original phrasing using "her" (and even "my," though a grammatical mismatch, actually doesn't sound so bad to me, but never mind that for now). Isn't it just a stylistic question?

Comment: I find both her and my to be awkward.  With "her", I find my mind casting around for who this person might be. It would have to be the "girl", but the girl is also the speaker,which makes it awkward, for me. So, yes, it is a stylistic question, and I think the form without rephrasing is "sub optimal".

Answer (score 0):

No need for her:

I am a young woman who likes *interacting* with people and *practicing* English.

You can't  practice someone else's English.

Answer (score -1):

You are speaking in the first person, you should pair **I am** with **my**.

You would use the second form if you were describing a group that you belong to: *I am one of those girls who likes to practice her English*.

Comment: The rationale for this answer doesn't hold - you say it should be "my" because of the use of the first person, but you're still speaking in the first person in your example sentence where you suggest "her" is appropriate.